# Reversing the order of words in a character array

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

The catch being that the position of special characters (for eg: '?' , ',' , ' ' , '.') should remain intact. So for an input string "Hello World, how are you?" The output would be "you are, how World Hello?". Now for the string without special characters, the O(n) algorithm is to reverse each word and then reverse the entire array, but that doesn't take into consideration the special characters.

The best algorithm I came up with is as follows. We traverse the array and push each word on top of the stack and then enqueue the special characters on a queue. And later, we pop elements from stack and queue simultaneously and conjoin them to form the required output.

Is there an in-place O(n) algorithm? If not, can you suggest an O(n^2) algorithm with no extra space. Also assume, you cannot use any string library functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse a string word by word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390846/reverse-a-string-word-by-word)

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879348/reverse-every-word-in-a-stringshould-handle-space

Comment: is using std::string (just for string representation) and std::istream ok?

Comment: Your algorithm is O(n)

Comment: OP is looking for an in place algorithm.

Comment: You cannot use string array. You will have to use character array to represent the string.

Comment: Split a string to elements, where element is a word or special character. Then reverse the order of words. It is easy to implement, ask if you'll meet some problems

Comment: Without special characters you have a sequence of words separated by one or more spaces; you reverse the order of the words while keeping the spaces. With special characters it's not much different: you have a sequence of words separated by one or more spaces and special characters; you reverse the order of the words while keeping the spaces and special characters.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan: I cannot see how does this follow the O(1) extra space constraint.

Answer (score 5):

So, here's an idea.

1) Initial string

```
"Hello World, how are you?"
```

2) Reverse string, but do not include any final special characters

```
"uoy era woh ,dlroW olleH?"
```

3) Reverse words in string

```
"you are how ,World Hello?"
```

4) Create an iterator (pointer, index, whatever you use) to the start and the end of the string, increment/deincrement each iterator until they hit non-words. By non words I mean blank space or a special character. So in this case, the increasing iterator would first come across the blank between 'you' and 'are', while the decreasing iterator would come across the blank space between 'world' and 'Hello' as shown below.

```
"you are how ,World Hello?"
    ^              ^
```

5) If there are no special characters, continue, if you hit a special character however. Reverse everything between the iterators, including the characters they point to. Below shows when this happens

```
"you are how ,World Hello?"
        ^    ^
```

6) And now we see the result of reversing this.

```
"you are, woh World Hello?"
```

Edit due to comment from johnchen902

7) Now reverse substring between these iterators, excluding the special character found in step (5).

```
"you are, how World Hello?"
```

8) return to step (5).

I haven't coded this yet and it was slightly tricky to explain but I hope you understand

Comment: Not working for `A,B,C D E`. Suggested fix: (7) Reverse the *substring* between iterators excluding the special character found in (5). (8) go to (5)

Comment: Good catch there johnchen902, I think that should make it work now. I guess my original solution would only work for an odd number of special characters. I'll edit my post to include your sugestion

Comment: Can you check for the test case 
"Hello World , How Are You?"
It seems to me, that the algorithm might not work. (Please note there is a space before the comma and after it too)

Consider test cases where multiple special characters appear simultaneously.

Comment: Hi user. So I haven't coded this but I did scribble it down and I got "You Are, How  World Hello?" with 2 spaces between 'How' and 'World' although I imagine you were hoping for
"You Are , How World Hello?" were you? If not perhaps more clarity on the rules are needed. You could modify steps 4-5 so that it iterators stop when they reach a white space that is not followed by a letter. It's a bit of a tricky wee puzzle to solve when you sit down and start considering the cases, but I think the basis is here.

Comment: Why hasn't the string " are how, World " reversed? That is the 1st instance of the algorithm meeting special characters.
I'll dry run the algorithm and get to coding it real soon, once I clear all my doubts.

Comment: So after the initial reverse and word reverse, it should look like...
"You Are How , World Hello?". The two iterators that walk through the string, let's call them Start and End. Start comes to the space between 'You' and 'Are'. End comes to the space between 'World' and 'Hello'. No special chars to far. Next Start comes to the blank between 'Are' and 'How', End comes to the ' , ' part. At this point it's how you want to deal with what End does. If it was me I would continue deincrementing End until it reached the comma (i.e., until the first non-letter after a blank). Then reverse etc...

Comment: Do you have any insight into how you figured this out? I have little to no insight into why this works / would work.

Comment: Hi Dukeling. So I guess the idea behind it is to realize that after the initial reverse then word reverse, a special character that was in, say the 2nd 'space' between words is now in the 2nd last 'space' between words. ('space' being any string separating two words). To get the special character back to the 2nd 'space', we simply reverse the substring containing the 2nd 'space' and the 2nd last 'space'. This puts the special character in the right place but reverses everything else. So as johnchen says, reverse everything again EXCEPT the special character you met and continue on.

Comment: The reason for doing a reverse and reverse again here rather than say, a swap, is that it keeps the correct spacing. Just doing a swap on the ',' and ' ' as in step (5) would have resulted in "you are,how World Hello?" where there would be a double space between 'how' and 'World'. There might be an easier way to solve this problem, but if this one does in fact work, it's an in-plane solution that only requires a reverse function.

Answer (score 1):

For an in-place algorithm simply create two iterators (that iterate on words), one reverse iterator and the other going forward.

Your loop will simply consist of something like:

```
while(FirstIteratorIsBefore(forward_iterator, backward_iterator)) {
  if(IsSpecialCharacter(*forward_iterator)) {
    ++forward_iterator;
  } else if(IsSpecialCharacter(*backward_iterator)) {
    ++backward_iterator;
  } else {
    // Swap the two
    Swap(forward_iterator, backward_iterator);
    ++forward_iterator;
    ++backward_iterator;
  }
}
```

Note: You will have to create your own simple word iterator for this logic to work, but that's easy enough to achieve.

Comment: You can't compare iterators of different categories (at least not standard compliant ones).

Comment: Thanks @jrok, I've updated the code to reflect that. Note that since these are your own iterators your FirstIteratorIsBefore is merely checking for the position in the original string it is iterating.

Comment: Given this is the only answer that gives a solution, can the down-voter please explain?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot follow your code. Would it be possible for you to explain it to me?

Comment: @user2560730 I am just about to leave now but read up about the stl iterators used in things like vector and map.

This solution uses the concept of iterators. You will need to do some work in the Swap() to be able to work for differently sized words where the text will have to be shifted in place and the internal positions within the iterators will need to be changed too.

Comment: `forward_iterator` and `backward_iterator` is some objects that iterating thru your string, stepping by one word or special character. `Swap` function swaps elements represented by those iterators. The most work here is implementing those iterators, but I like this solution

Comment: This "iterator" would need to know the starting position and length of the word it hangs on to. The amount of memory overhead is constant, 2 words per iterator, so that's okay. The problem is swap function when the words differ in size. This involves quite an amount of shifting the characters of the rest of the string around.

Comment: It seems like the only solution with O(1) extra space, so author will have a fun time implementing iterators and swap. I'd suggest to use pseudocode to design its algoritm - first write it on human language, then translate it on c++